# Questions about line heights:

Tags: css

Code for the below test: http://jsfiddle.net/fXdjm/

Questions about line heights:

- Please refer first box.*What will be length of the distance between
  red border and the text top(say head of L) of the first line("Gg -
  First Line")?*
- Please refer second box.*What will be length of the distance between
  head of "S" in "Second" and head of "l" in "normal height"?*

By the term head of "a character", i refer to the top of that character. This is because, a line may contain tall and small characters like "lg"

Comment: Which is the question by the way?

Comment: Can't understand the questions, please rephrase.

Comment: Read up on line-height to understand how it is calculated: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/line-height. The distance between the top of the G and the S (capital letters) is approximately the line-height minus the font-size / 2.

Here is some more explanation:

**Content area**
The font-size determines the *content area* which includes the area for capital letters and lowercase letters such as p,g, etc.

**Leading**
Line-height minus the font-size is called the *leading*

**Half-leading**
Space between top of capitals and the top of the box is called the *half-leading*.

This simple formula generally holds, however in cases where the line-height is smaller than the font-size it doesn't!

Comment: thanks for the link. very useful. So the space between the top red border and head of the "L" should be (40-16)/2 which is 12, but, when i measure it, its 15px. Please clarify.

Comment: Anything between the end of the box (line-height) and the border is padding. Following the standard model: *padding* | *border* | *margin*

Comment: padding for all divs are zero.

Comment: You may have to account for special letters such as É, see: http://jsfiddle.net/aKMAY/5/

Comment: i'm again struck with a doubt.. Please see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/neWZp/  .The content area is from the start of accent to the end of descend. In this fiddle this should be 50 px, but  its measuring more than 50px.Please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to figure out the top half-leading.

If your font-size is 12px, and your line-height is 14px, you will have a half-leading of 2px (above and below the glyphs).

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height